# Why do I get yearling badges on Meta? I'm not active on Meta

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I'm active on Stack Overflow, earning sufficient rep each year to earn a yearling badge.
I'm not active at all on SO meta.

Why award me a yearling badge on Meta when I don't participate here?

Are meta rep and SO rep put in the same bucket?

Comment: You were active on MSO, upvoted 4 times and received the [Supporter badge in 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter?userid=7552).

Comment: Why? Because no good deed goes unpunished 

Comment: *I'm not active at all on SO meta.* ... That just changed, right? Welcome!

Comment: And now you just garnered the meta-ironic badge, congratulations!

Comment: It's an exclusive club, me and Alanis Morissette

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The criteria for the [Yearling badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) are

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

On a child meta, both the age of your profile, and the reputation you've earned are inherited from the parent (main) site. Since these are the only criteria, you should receive as many yearling badges on meta as you do on the main site.

Comment: Fun fact: You do not have to earn the 200 reputation points every year. With just 2000 reputation points earned the first year, a user will get the Yearling every year for 10 years.

Comment: Good to know I'm set for the next <strike>century</strike> millenium (math is hard) :/